# Default values of class fields in DART

Tags: oop, dart, constructor

I know it's a silly question but I'm stuck on it for quite a while now.

How to set default values of class members in DART.
This is how i provide the default values of the members but it's always **null**.

If these values are provided in constructor then it should use those values otherwise use the default value.

```
class BillingInfoDetails {
  bool billToClient = false;
  String clientName = "";
  String reasonOfTravel = "";
  String remarks = "";

  BillingInfoDetails({
    this.billToClient,
    this.clientName,
    this.reasonOfTravel,
    this.remarks,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
class BillingInfoDetails {
  bool billToClient;
  String clientName;
  String reasonOfTravel;
  String remarks;

  BillingInfoDetails({
    this.billToClient = false,
    this.clientName = "",
    this.reasonOfTravel = "",
    this.remarks = "",
  });
}
```

You can find this information in the Dart Tour Guide: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters in section "Default parameter values".

Comment: class BillingInfoDetails {
  List<String> names;  
  BillingInfoDetails ({this.names = const <String>[]});  
}